# How to get next value (after , value)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have data like this =

```
Hi,I,Am,Here,to,BP,23,HP,34,COST,45
```

I want to get value for BP for HP and For COST so how can I get value next to , .

explaination

```
const array = [BP,HP,COST]
const string = ["HI","I","AM","BP","20","HP","35","COST","30"]

expected output = Value of BP is 20, Value of HP is 35, Value of COST is 30
```

Comment: you mean need to get {BP: 23}, {HP: 34}, {COST: 45} ?

Comment: yes right I just want to value next to BP,HP,COST as I already have keys HP,BP,COST in separate array I just took keys from that array and check here that ok I have to pick value for this key . like this

Comment: please check explaination block

Comment: Assuming you know the keys to BP, HP and COST (and I am not misunderstanding your question) - you can just +1 the index.

Comment: You can get their index without a problem too if they occur only once in your array and then +1 the index as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get index of that key. For example: From your array, the index of BP is **5**, the index of next value (23) is **6**

From that example, we can have this logic (`array` is your name of variable)

```js
const array = ["BP","HP","COST"]
const string = ["HI","I","AM","BP","20","HP","35","COST","30"]
const newArray = []
for (const key of array) {
  newArray.push(string[string.indexOf(key) + 1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the keys to BP, HP and COST (and I am not misunderstanding your question) - you can just +1 the index.

```
var data = ["Hi", "I", "Am", "Here", "to", "BP", 23, "HP", 34, "COST", 45];
var indexBP = data.indexOf("BP");
var BP = data[indexBP + 1]; // BP = 23
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = ['BP','HP','COST']
const string = ["HI","I","AM","BP","20","HP","35","COST","30"]

let output = "";
array.forEach(x => {
  output += `Value of ${x} is ${string[string.indexOf(x) + 1]} `
})

console.log(output)
```

You can have a simple loop and combine with `indexOf + 1` to get the value you want, assuming the position is predictable

Answer (score 0):

This may be one possible implementation to obtain the `Expected Output`.

```js
const strArr = ["HI", "I", "AM", "BP", "20", "HP", "35", "COST", "30"];
console.log(
    ['BP', 'HP', 'COST']
  .map(
    k => `Value of ${k} is ${strArr[strArr.indexOf(k) + 1]}`
  ).join(', ')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just plus 1 the index

```js
const array = ['BP', 'HP', 'COST'];
const string = ["HI","I","AM","BP","20","HP","35","COST","30"];

let output = array.map(
    k => `Value of ${k} is ${string[string.indexOf(k) + 1]}`
).join(', ');

output += '.';
console.log(output);
```